# Увеличение времени исполнения кода

Tags: c++, mpi, openmp

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: Есть код, написанный не одним человеком, который работает с использованием MPI. В части последовательного кода, было принято сделать распараллеливание при помощи OpenMP.
Для этого, в последовательную функцию были добавлены прагмы #pragma openmp.
Код был отлажен, и проверен.  Распределенный код на MPI - не менялся. Результат работы программы, до и после изменения, полностью совпадает.
Но, возникла следующая проблема: код распределенный на MPI стал работать медленнее. Замедление около 10-15%.

Программа собиралась как на компиляторе intel 2013, так и на 2016. MVAPICH-1.2.
Запускалась на 32 и 64 потоках.
При изменении числа нитей OpenMP до 2, замедление "MPI-кода" - исчезает.
Программа написана на С++.

Comment: А там код-то параллелится вообще?

Comment: Да, код в данной секции распараллелился. Это видно как по выдачам, так и по времени исполнения.

Comment: Вы говорите, что работать стало медленнее. Это как раз может говорить о том, что код в принципе нельзя параллелить.

Comment: Возможно я не до конца объяснил как выглядит код, поэтому ниже приведу схему:

Comment: 1) Инициализация; Рассылка данных на MPI нити; 2) Код на MPI; Сборка на одну нить; 3) Последовательный код; 4) Проверка условия завершения; 4.а) Возврат к пункту 2. Рассылка данных на MPI нити; 4.б) Завершение.

Comment: Замер времени осуществлен для каждого пункта. Т.е. по завершению, я могу сравнить время выполнения каждого куска кода. Для исключения погрешности замера, делал по 3 запуска, каждой версии кода, и выбирал наименьшее время.

Comment: Существуют алгоритмы, которые не параллелятся. Может, ваш из таких.

Comment: Как уже сказано, алгоритм может не поддаваться распараллеливанию. Также издержки на параллельность могут превзойти профит от параллельного выполнения. Всё-таки обсуждать кота в мешке не особо продуктивное занятие.